# On proving that if a commuting rectangle's right and outer square are pullbacks, then so is the left square.

Tags: proof-writing, category-theory

I'm trying to prove that if a commutative rectangle

\begin{array}
\ p \xrightarrow{i} p' \xrightarrow{m}  a \\
\downarrow^{j}  \quad   \downarrow^k  \quad  \downarrow^o \\
d\  \xrightarrow{l} b  \xrightarrow{n}  c
\end{array}

for some category $\mathcal{C}$ verifies that both the 'outer' rectangle and the right square are pullbacks, then the left square is a pullback. There other direction is also true, and I've already proved it, but this implication seems a bit trickier. So far, I've done the obvious: let $x \in \mathcal{C}$ be an object with

\begin{array}
\ x \xrightarrow{\phi} p' \\
\downarrow^{\psi}  \quad   \downarrow^k  \\
d \xrightarrow{l} b
\end{array}

a cone with summit $x$, i.e. a pair $(x \xrightarrow{\phi} p',x \xrightarrow{\psi} d)$ with $k \phi = l \psi$. To conclude, I'd have to show that both $\phi$ and $\psi$ factor trough a unique morphism $x \xrightarrow{h} p$.

Since the outer square is a pullback, composing $\phi$ with $m$ gives a cone over $d \xrightarrow{nl} c \xleftarrow{o} a$, and since $p$ is a pullback, we have a unique morphism $h:x \to p$ such that $m\phi = mih$ and $\psi = jh$. Thus, it would be sufficient to see that $\phi = ih$. However, $m$ need not be a monomorphism, so I presume that to show this I should use that the right square is a pullback as well.

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Steve Awodey's book has a proof of this if I remember correctly.

Comment: I've just looked it up, and, to quote him: 'Proof. Diagram chase'. This is probably obvious provided that you have some familiarity with the subject, which I unfortunately don't. If you can and have the time, I'd really appreciate at least a subtle hint on which path to follow next.

Comment: You are correct $m$ need not be a mono, but $m$ and $k$ (being pullback projections) are jointly monic i.e. they satisfy: $mf=mg$ and $kf=kg$ implies $f=g$. See if you can use this to complete your proof.

Comment: @Nex I think I've managed to do it with your hint. Would you care to check my work? It would feel odd to accept my own answer without any external verification.

Comment: You can use AMScd to draw (rectangular) commutative diagrams: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram

Comment: @DerekElkins thanks! That's really helpful, I was already losing it just by trying to adjust the arrows to point where I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so, I think I've got it by using the hint provided by Nex in the comments. First, I proved the actual hint,

> *Proposition*. If the following diagram is a pulback,

\begin{array}
\ p' \xrightarrow{m}  a \\
\downarrow^k  \quad  \downarrow^o \\
b  \xrightarrow{n}  c
\end{array}

> and $f,g : y \to p'$ are such that $mf  = mg$ and $kf = kg$, then $f = g$.

*Proof*. By hypothesis, the cones with summit $y$ given by $(mf, kf)$ and $(mg, kg)$ are the same, and thus there exists a unique morphism $q$ such that $mf = mq = mg$ , and $kf  = kq = kg$. Since both $f$ and $g$ verify this, we have that $f = q = g$.

Now having proved that, and since I had already seen that $m\phi = mih$, it will be sufficient to prove that $k\phi = kih$. By commutativity of the rectangle, we know that $ki = lj$ and so, in effect,

$$
kih = ljh \stackrel{(*)}= l\psi \stackrel{(**)}= k\phi
$$

with $(*)$ proven in the original question, and $(**)$ given by the fact that $(\phi, \psi)$ are a cone and in this setting, a cone over $d \xrightarrow{l} b \xleftarrow{k} p'$ implies $l\psi = k \phi$.

Comment: That looks good.

Comment: @Nex great, thanks again for your time!